# How to render d3.js chart from vue.js method (passing target div)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js

I have my basic vue code that looks like this:

```
new Vue({

    el : '#friendlist',

    data : {

        friends : []

    },

    methods : {

        fetchStats : function(){

            const axios_data = {
                _token  : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            };

            axios.post('/friend-stats/all', axios_data).then(response => {

                this.friends = response.data;

            });

        }
    },

    mounted : function(){

        this.fetchStats();

    },
```

Now, for each `friend` in the `friends` array, I need to render a d3.js chart. I have a method in a different JS file that works correctly, it's called `create_spider_chart(friend, target)`. The `friend` variable contains a member of the friends array from our vue component above, and `target` is the target element the chart should be appended to. This is where the problem arises.

If I do this in the response of the axios call:

```
this.friends = response.data.data;
let target;
for(let i=0;i<this.friends.length;i++){
     target = '.spider-graphic-mini[data-id="'+this.friends[i].id+'"]';
     create_spider_chart(this.friends[i], target);   //d3.js
}
```

The element `.spider-graphic-mini[data-id="'+this.friends[i].id+'"]` does exist in the HTML:

```
<template v-for="(friend,key) in friends">
     <div class="col-md-6 friend-panel p-3">
          <h5>@{{ friend.name }}</h5>
          <div class="spider-graphic-mini mb-4" :data-id="friend.id"></div>
     </div>
</template>
```

But, when I pass that identifier to the `create_spider_chart` function, the element apparently doesn't exist. So `$(target)` has `length=0` and the function doesn't know where to create the chart.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used d3 so take this with grain of salt.

JS is single threaded and Vue DOM update process is asynchronous. The moment you assign  content into your `friends` array, Vue had no chance yet to render your template with new data. That's why your element doesn't exist yet.

What you need is to use `$nextTick(callback)` to essentially way until Vue re-renders your template and run all the code depending on existence of elements inside the callback.

[This piece of documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue) explains it...

Comment: This did the trick: this.$nextTick(function () {//call charting library to render charts});